# How do I mark records red/green if they appear partially in another table?

Tags: laravel

I have a table "Books" and a table "Borrowed". In the table "Books" are fields like serial number, name, ean etc.. In the "Borrowed" table there are books that are currently temporarily out of stock. Now I also have a "Books search" which I have built up as follows:

```
    class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('books.search');
    }

        public function search (Request $request)
      {

        if($request->ajax())
        {
          $output="";
          $books=DB::table('books')->where('name','LIKE','%'.$request->search."%")->get();

          if($books)
          {

            foreach ($books as $key => $books)
            {

              $output.='<tr>'.
              '<td>'.$books->id.'</td>'.
              '<td>'.$books->name.'</td>'.
              '<td>'.$books->ean.'</td>'.
              '<td>'.$books->serialnumber.'</td>'.
              '</tr>';
            }

            return Response ($output);
          }
        }
      }
}
```

The table is displayed correctly with all books in the inventory. My question now is how can I mark borrowed books red in this search table and mark books that can be borrowed green?

Thank you for your help I appreciate this very much.

Comment: You should probably post some sample data for both tables, and then show the output you expect.

Comment: hi Zedex, welcome to stackoverflow. Have you read the documentation for [laravel on views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views)? you can use `if` to differentiate between records.

Comment: @Bagus Tesa Thank you I have read it but it has helped me little.  I know how to declare an if but especially in this case it's hard for me to realize it because I can't imagine how to write it exactly.

Comment: @Zedex, how do we know that the book is borrowed? if we have something like `isBorrowed()` that returns true if its borrowed, we probably can do something `@if($book->isBorrowed())` within the `@for`.